# How to Update of multiple lines with join in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have this update in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE #actives
SET
    liquidity = CASE
                WHEN a.ativ_day_conv <> '19000101'
                THEN DATEDIFF(d, @Dt_fin, b.bond_vcto)
                WHEN b.bond_liquidity = -1
                THEN DATEDIFF(d, @Dt_fin, b.bond_vcto)
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @Dt_fin, DATEADD(d, b.bond_liquidity, a.minor_date)) > 0
                THEN DATEDIFF(d, @Dt_fin, DATEADD(d, b.bond_liquidity, a.minor_date))
                ELSE 0
            END
FROM #actives a
INNER JOIN rc_bonds b ON b.ativ_id = a.ativ_id
INNER JOIN rc_actives x ON x.ativ_id = a.ativ_id
INNER JOIN rc_group_actives g ON g.grat_id = x.grat_id
    AND g.grat_compromisse_sn = 'n';
```

And I have the "same" update logic in PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE actives a
SET
    liquidity = CASE                    
                WHEN a.ativ_day_conv <> '19000101'
                THEN DATE_PART('day', b.bond_vcto - p_Dt_fin)
                WHEN b.bond_liquidity = -1
                THEN DATE_PART('day', b.bond_vcto - p_Dt_fin)
                WHEN DATE_PART('day', DATEADD('d'::varchar(1), b.bond_liquidity::int, a.minor_date) - p_Dt_fin) > 0
                THEN DATE_PART('day', DATEADD('d'::varchar(1), b.bond_liquidity::int, a.minor_date) - p_Dt_fin )
                ELSE 0
            END
FROM atives a
INNER JOIN rc_bonds b ON b.ativ_id = a.ativ_id
INNER JOIN rc_atives x ON x.ativ_id = a.ativ_id
INNER JOIN rc_group_atives g ON g.grat_id = x.grat_id
    AND g.grat_compromisse_sn = 'n';
```

But in PostgreSQL it's getting the same value for all rows, how can I do this to work properly?

PS: I just tried Gordon's answer (thank you again!), but I get the error below:

> SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"
> Hint: There is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

How I solved:

Again, thank you Gordon! You helped me a lot!

Can't access the "a" table on the JOIN clause, so I replace it with the "x" (do the same). I do can access the "a" table on WHERE clause. So here it's.

```
UPDATE actives a
SET
    liquidity = CASE                    
                WHEN a.ativ_day_conv <> '19000101'
                THEN DATE_PART('day', b.bond_vcto - p_Dt_fin)
                WHEN b.bond_liquidity = -1
                THEN DATE_PART('day', b.bond_vcto - p_Dt_fin)
                WHEN DATE_PART('day', DATEADD('d'::varchar(1), b.bond_liquidity::int, a.minor_date) - p_Dt_fin) > 0
                THEN DATE_PART('day', DATEADD('d'::varchar(1), b.bond_liquidity::int, a.minor_date) - p_Dt_fin )
                ELSE 0
            END
FROM rc_bonds b
INNER JOIN rc_atives x ON x.ativ_id = b.ativ_id
INNER JOIN rc_group_atives g ON g.grat_id = x.grat_id
    AND g.grat_compromisse_sn = 'n'
WHERE b.ativ_id = a.ativ_id;
```

Comment: hq1 sorry, its just here. on my script its correct :)

Comment: Add your solution as an answer rather than an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The logic isn't the same in Postgres.  The two handle the `update` table differently.  In Postgres, *it should not be repeated in the `FROM`*.  So:

```
UPDATE actives a
    SET liquidity = CASE                    
                    WHEN a.ativ_day_conv <> '19000101'
                    THEN DATE_PART('day', b.bond_vcto - p_Dt_fin)
                    WHEN b.bond_liquidity = -1
                    THEN DATE_PART('day', b.bond_vcto - p_Dt_fin)
                    WHEN DATE_PART('day', DATEADD('d'::varchar(1), b.bond_liquidity::int, a.minor_date) - p_Dt_fin) > 0
                    THEN DATE_PART('day', DATEADD('d'::varchar(1), b.bond_liquidity::int, a.minor_date) - p_Dt_fin )
                    ELSE 0
                END
    FROM rc_bonds b JOIN
         rc_atives x
         ON x.ativ_id = b.ativ_id JOIN
         rc_group_atives g
         ON g.grat_id = x.grat_id AND
            g.grat_compromisse_sn = 'n';
    WHERE b.ativ_id = a.ativ_id
```

Comment: Hey! I just tried this and its gets: SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"
  Hint: There is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: I got it... Can't access the "a" table on the JOIN clause, so I replace it with the "x" (do the same). I do can access the "a" table on WHERE clause.

Comment: @javaMan . . . Just use `b.ativ_id` in the `FROM` clause.  They are the same, based on the `WHERE`.